# How to use gcc instead of clang on macOS, specially M1?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang, apple-m1

I code in C++. I was a Windows user, recently switched to mac. I downloaded gcc-10 from homebrew but still, whenever I compile on any editor, it got compiled with Clang.

Then I deleted Clang by going to the directory where it was stored, I thought it will then compile with GCC.
But now it stops compiling and throwing error messages.

**Q. Why do I wish to use gcc instead of clang?**
-> Clang doesn't have <bits/stdc++.h> header and while solving one question I got to know it doesn't have unordered map also [(read on Stack Overflow later)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444908/clang-6-not-supporting-unordered-mapmerge).

-> And I don't know what more is not there in clang.

How can I find out either **how to successfully compile C++ using gcc on MAC** or **all the differences between clang and gcc** and how should I manage them?

Even I talked with Apple Care for about 45 mins and they also don't know the solution.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: And the question you link to only talks about `unordered_map::merge`, not `unordered_map` in general. `merge` was added in C++17 so it's probably available now (three years after that question).

Comment: In short, if you _actually_ "code in C++" (instead of some GNU dialect) then you should have no problems switching to another compiler.

Comment: You may find [brew](https://brew.sh/) helpful, and then you can `brew install gcc` to install GCC.

Comment: I don't think gcc is supported on that platform yet.